# How can the Community user bot edit questions?

Tags: support, editing, user-accounts, community-user

It seems like the [Community](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) user that's supposed to be *"a background process to keep this site clean"*, somehow figured out that [an answer contained an unformatted quote and formatted it](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community).

Is it really THAT smart? Or am I being rick-rolled here? User id of -1 suggests that no, it really is a special user.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Community makes edits when an *anonymous user* makes a suggested edit. An unregistered or registered user has an identity on the site that we can link, but someone who entirely lacks an account doesn't. As a result, Community owns those edits.

Comment: I thought anonymous users get called something like user93823.

Comment: That's a user who simply hasn't picked a display name