# User Community Added Content to an Answer

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can the bot (user Community) edit questions?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3098/how-can-the-bot-user-community-edit-questions)

I did see this similar question [How can the bot (user Community) edit questions?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3098/how-can-the-bot-user-community-edit-questions).

I saw something similar happen here [Where are all of the hidden vault symbols for the “Cult of the Vault” challenges?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/84860/revisions)

The other answer did not make it clear to me. If anonymous users edit something, the bot Community owns the edit.

But do you not require privileges to edit something? How are anonymous users able to edit anything? Again sorry for such a basic question, I am still learning things about this community (no-pun).

Comment: I believe that anyone can suggest edits, but you need the certain level of rep to edit without going through community vetting of the edit. It is possible that an anonymous user made the edit, and someone with the rep necessary approved it.

Comment: You require privileges to edit, but not to suggest an edit. When an anonymous user suggests an edit and it's approved, it appears as though the community user made the edit.